# PHP curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) too slow

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I use this method to get facebook api data. just a search query. but I find use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` cost more time during a `curl` time (over 10+ seconds).

Is there other `curl` method can run faster?

**NOTE: I am now testing in localhost**

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=".$token."&q=dallas&type=post&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__). '/file.crt'); the way as Lumbendil recommend, download a crt file via firefox. still slowly.
$body= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

**PS:I do not want to use a `SDK`, becuase I failed set `SDK` in localhost test. Although I have read many articles of how to set in localhost. I have set `http://127.0.0.1/facebook` as my callback url. But just failed. So I still want to get an easy curl way.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a .crt file and verify against that instead of ignoring SSL verification, [as explained here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

To keep all the information in one place: In your code, you should write the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/crt/file.crt');
```

To obtain the certificate, you should go with the browser to the page, and then with "view certificate" you have to export it. Remember that you must export it as **X.509 Certificate (PEM)** for this to work. For a more detailed guide on how to export the certificate, visit the link provided.

Comment: Won't this cause trouble when the certificate changes?

Comment: In fact it should cause trouble if the certificate sign changes, that's the whole point of a SSL connection, to avoid the posiblity of someone replacing the URL.

Comment: I mean, when Facebook replaces it because it has expired. For instance, the current certificate will have been replaced by December of 2013.

Comment: In the link, it explains how to get the certificate of the top entity. When that one expires, yes, it'd need to be renewed. To do so, you could setup a cron wich is executed weekly or monthly.

Comment: @Lumbendil, not worked, I followed the article and download teh file from `https://graph.facebook.com/...` then save in the same folder with my php file. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'file.crt');` or `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/file.crt');` or return `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @cj333 Check the output you're getting (doing a `var_dump($body);`) to see if the problem is here or if it's somewhere else. I'll mark this as favourite since I've worked with Facebook graph API but I don't have the code I used for it here.

Comment: How about using the [certificate](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt) that comes with the SDK?

Comment: @ifaour, I tried to set `SDK` in localhost, but noe success. `You are not Connected.`. I have set my callback url like `http://127.0.0.1/facebook`

Comment: @Lumbendil, set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__). '/file.crt');` can run well, but still cost long long time.

Comment: @cj333 have you tried the way the PHP-SDK doing it (check the `base_facebook.php` file)? maybe setup the same [example](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) to check if you get the same timeout?

Comment: @ifaour, yes, I tried in `localhost` ,set my app id, secrect, and my callback url in facebook, like `http://127.0.0.1/facebook`, the `example` return `You are not Connected.`, maybe I met some trouble in `local test`. If can, can u help me detach the `curl` set in `php-sdk / src / base_facebook.php` line `739`? Thanks.

Comment: @cj333 I looked at my example, and it can only be something wich is related with the other options you're using. Try testing the **https** for a public API call without any other options except the `RETURNTRANSFER` to on and the `SSL_VERIFYPEER` to off.

Comment: @Lumbendil, I have modify the code in my question, only `RETURNTRANSFER` `true` and  `SSL_VERIFYPEER` false. but still slowly.

Comment: This entire answer seems confused. The question says _not checking_ the certificates at all is too slow, so how would adding certs to check make it any faster?

Answer (score 2):

If ignoring to check a certificate takes 10 seconds, the problem is not with the certificate or with the checking and quite frankly, it probably isn't with SSL at all.

Ignoring to check the certificate should be very fast and not be measurable compared to how long the rest of the SSL handshake procedure takes.

To properly track down the problem, I would recommend you use the curl command line tool and its [--trace-ascii](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-ascii) and [--trace-time](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-time) options to see what seems to take time. You may need to snoop on the network with wireshark or similar to get an even better picture of what's going on.

I can't see how the other suggestions of *adding* a certificate check to the mix will make anything faster.

Comment: have u tried a graph search by yourself? I am puzzle my slowly. I do not know the slowly caused by `localhost` or if move to a real server will run more quicker.

Comment: I'm the libcurl maintainer and lead developer, I've done my fair share of using curl in many situations (albeit not with PHP) but I've never faced this weird situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, but if you do wish to use the SDK you can work around the local issue by editing your hosts file and adding localhost.local for 127.0.0.1. /etc/hosts on a linux machine and C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on a windows machine.

Then in the Facebook app settings, simply set localhost.local as your domain and set your site url accordingly.

You should be ready to go then.